# Parsing multiple JSON strings

Tags: android

I would like to thank all the users in this community for helping me get as far as I am in my project today.

I now need your help once again. So far, I am able to establish a connection in my project from this JSON link (REMOVED FOR PRIVACY CONCERNS)

The problem is I am only able to parse one string, (firstName)

Here is my code:

```
public class JSONActivity extends Activity { 
static TextView http; 
HttpClient client; 
JSONObject json; 

    final static String URL = "REMOVED FOR PRIVACY CONCERNS

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        http = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.http); 
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        new Read().execute("firstName"); 

    } 

    public JSONObject getpw(String password) throws ClientProtocolException, 
            IOException, JSONException { 
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL); 
        url.append(password); 

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString()); 
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(get); 
        int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 
        if (status == 200) { 
            HttpEntity e = r.getEntity(); 
            String data = EntityUtils.toString(e); 
            JSONObject getname = new JSONObject(data); 

            return getname; 
        } else { 
            Toast.makeText(JSONActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
            return null; 
        } 
    } 

    public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> { 

        @Override 
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            try { 
                json = getpw("trustme"); 
                return json.getString("firstName"); 
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } catch (JSONException e) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 

            return null; 
        } 

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            http.setText(result); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

My question is, how can I parse multiple strings rather than just "firstName"?

Comment: Can't you parse everything in doInBackground and return as an array of strings or via a field?

Comment: Thats what I also assumed, but it seems like in my code where it says " return json.getString("firstName"); " it is only allowing me to return one.

Comment: I believe you can have your Read class derived from AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<String> > then your doInBackground will have to return ArrayList<String> which you can populate and return then as you need

Comment: Would you care to show me an example, Alex?

Comment: I believe you can just replace the 3rd String template argument in your AsyncTask with HashMap<String> and also replace String return type of doInBackground with the same. Then you create new HashMap<String> result variable in doInBackground() populate it with the parsed values something like res.put("firstName", yourFirstNameData) and other such puts and return the hashmap.

Comment: Alex, Ive tried doing what you suggested however, I get the folowing error when I try to replace the third string template in my AsyncTask "Incorrect number of arguments for type HashMap<K,V>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments" Im not quite sure how to resolce it. Thanks for all the help you have given me. I do appreciate it.

Comment: It should be HashMap<String, String>, sorry. You are a student doing some assignment?

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Alex. I am actually just interested in developing apps for my own personal use. At times it can be fun, but other times (like this) It can be really frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it all by doing the following:

```
String firstname = json.getString("firstName");
String lastname = json.getString("lastName");
int checkedIn = json.getInt("checkedIn");
int updated = json.getInt("checkedindatetime");

JSONObject address = json.getJSONObject("address");
String streetaddress = address.getString("streetAddress");
String city = address.getString("city");
etc...

JSONArray phoneNumbers = json.getJSONArray("phoneNumber");
String type = phoneNumbers.getJSONObject(0).getString("type");
etc...
```

Hope this helps.

A good resource for looking at json, is this [validator](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).

Comment: Thank you, coder. I guess my question really is, how do i set it up so I can view all the strings in a textview. would it be for example, String firstName = textview.getText().toString(); ?

Comment: Why don't you make an object that has everything you need from the json, add each of the string to the respective values in the object, then return the object? That way you would have all your values store ed that you could access.

Comment: sounds so simple to do, but easier said than done lol. I'll poke around for a bit and give your suggestion a try. Thanks!